# Available Memory Size in Visual Studio C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, memory-management

I am developing a "pyramid" game that uses a Minimax tree that searches for the "best" move .. but my game is freezing.

My deduction is that it's a memory problem but I am using only 124kb of memory. How much memory can I allocate with the new operator? Or, what is the memory limit assigned to my application by default.

Comment: What do you mean by "freezing"? And could you show some (minimal) code that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: Doesn't sound like lack of memory to me. Sounds like you have an infinite loop; faulty logic.

Comment: Have you tried debugging the code? When the program 'freezes', pause it and see what's going on (ie. examine the callstack and local variables). Your deduction is not a deduction, it's only a guess until you've debugged the code. Guessing in software dev is a recipe for a weary life.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OS does decide how much memory you'll be able to allocate at each given time, making your question impossible to answer.

I would be you, I would show the faulty code instead of thinking it's the compiler or the environnement that does something wrong. 124kb is nothing on most platforms.

If it's not throwing a bad_alloc, I really doubt your new call will fail. It's certainly not the real problem.

Comment: ok nice this is a university project. a classmate has this problem but my application is running fine with a tree depth of 4 so no problem = thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

You might also consider looking at possible stack overflow.  Especially if your algorithm involves recursion.

Answer (score 0):

There is no limit by default.

If you allocate smallish objects, you can generally get 1 to 1.5 GB of them on 32-bit Windows.

Comment: Up to 2GB to be precise, if large-addressing is not enabled. Otherwise it may go up to 3GB.

Comment: @Ajay - but some of the address space is used by code, and some is often unusable because of fragmentation, so 1.5 GB is more of a practical limit. Way more than 124k though!

Comment: I agree. But technically it is 2GB. Secondly, the code isn't 500 MB, most generally!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think a memory problem would cause your game to freeze before it would cause it to crash.  You probably have an infinite loop somewhere.  If you had a problem with the memory, I would imagine you would get an error message of some sort as opposed to the loop issue where it will just hang.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not you are consuming all of memory, but you are consuming all of CPU!
Check the logic of your game program.